# Angular / Typescript object cannot reach with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data which I'm linking to ngModel but I'm having issues.

Here is the data and code example:

```
dat = {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "",
      "subitem": {
        "subName": "",
      }
};
```

If I use:

```
[(ngModel)]="dat.name"
```

it will work fine and no give any errors but if I try to reach the subName:

```
[(ngModel)]="dat.subitem.subName"
```

or

```
[(ngModel)]="dat.subitem[0].subName"
```

I get an error:

Cannot read property .. of undefined

How can I reach subName?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="dat.subitem.subName"` should work fine. `[(ngModel)]="dat.subitem[0].subName"` would definitely give an error.

Comment: [(ngModel)]="dat.subitem.subName"

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo? Like `subitem` vs `subItem`?

Comment: It works in the fiddle, need more info. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwqhzq

Comment: There is a missing code because this is working fine dat.subitem.subName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dat.subitem` is not a array it is a object so you can access the object `value` like this 
`[(ngModel)]="dat.subitem?.subName"`

Comment: I'm getting: Template parse errors: Parser Error: The '?.'

Comment: remove the `?` and try again.